# Excel VB Search Specific Worksheet

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am trying to search a specific worksheet (CSI Tracker) in a specific workbook (CSI).

I have the code below:

```
Function FindAllOnWorksheets(InWorkbook As Workbook, _
            InWorksheets As String, "CSI Tracker", _
            SearchAddress As String, _
            FindWhat As Variant, _
            Optional LookIn As XlFindLookIn = xlValues, _
            Optional LookAt As XlLookAt = xlWhole, _
            Optional SearchOrder As XlSearchOrder = xlByRows, _
            Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
            Optional BeginsWith As String = vbNullString, _
            Optional EndsWith As String = vbNullString, _
            Optional BeginEndCompare As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare) As Variant
```

Any help, would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this code will loop through the worksheet names of a workbook and if that sheet exist then it will be activated.

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'a specific workbook (CSI)
    If ws.Name = "CSI Tracker" Then
        ws.Activate
        Exit For
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

'you can name as Workbooks("CSI.xls")

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Workbooks("Brief v13.xls").Activate
For Each ws In Workbooks("CSI.xls").Sheets
    If ws.Name = "CSI Tracker" Then
        ws.Activate
        Exit For
    End If
Next ws
```

End Sub